# how to increase the size of Jupyter notebook plot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Using the calmap package I create a heatmap calendar but I would like to know how to increase the font or the size of the plot.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calmap')))
import pandas as pd
import calmap

all_days = pd.date_range('1/15/2014', periods=700, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)

calmap.yearplot(events, year=2015)
```

[image]

Comment: That's one useful trick to have a readable seed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/_modules/calmap.html):

```
def yearplot(data, year=None, how='sum', vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap='Reds',
         fillcolor='whitesmoke', linewidth=1, linecolor=None,
         daylabels=calendar.day_abbr[:], dayticks=True,
         monthlabels=calendar.month_abbr[1:], monthticks=True, ax=None,
         **kwargs):
```

There is an `ax` parameter. It corresponds to the axis on which the figure must be draw. First create an axis with the desired size.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 10))
calmap.yearplot(events, year=2015, ax=ax)
```

EDIT: For font size, work on the axis. Something like this:

```
for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
         ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(20)
```

Answer (score 31):

This should fix your issue

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=20,20
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко That is a bit strange, are you getting any errors ??

Comment: seems like it sould be %matplotlib inline
 and the plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] should be in the exact cell the plt.plot is (before it)

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко are you using pop up for your visualizations ??, my code only addresses the figures plotted inside the jupyter notebook itself.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook` allows this to work for me while `inline` does not.